# How to not show the message 'You haven't voted on questions in a while, questions need votes too!' when I have ran out of votes?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, voting

The other day, I used up all my votes trying to earn the Sportsmanship badge.

Okay, so I was voting all the answers I could. Obviously, I only voted the ones which I truly thought were good, but was jealous, so didn't vote up, I'm being REALLY honest here =)

Anyway, so then I nearly used up all my votes on one of the questions, and it said that 'You have 1 vote left today'. So then, of course, I switched to another question, and upvoted an answer with more votes than mine. Note that that was my last vote for that day. And then, it said `You haven't voted on questions in a while, questions need votes too!`.

I think that's a bit of an incorrect statement, since I already used up all my votes anyway.

Is this intentional?

Comment: *"but was jealous, so didn't vote up"*...are you saying you downvoted every answer you thought was truly good?

Comment: @Bart didn't upvote, didn't downvote.

Comment: I was going to say, downvotes won't get you the sportsmanship badge. :) That whole passage reads a bit strange though.

Comment: I guess you gave up pretty quickly. [*still no sportsmanship badge*](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1136709/think123?tab=badges) :-)

Answer (score 7):

Well, you will have more votes tomorrow... Consider it advice for the future. I don't really see any need to code in a check to see how many votes you actually have left. The message isn't worded in any way that you should vote on questions *now*, just that you should also consider questions when voting.